# `for_fd': not a socket file descriptor

Tags: ruby, sockets, fastcgi, redmine

I've installed Redmine, it's working fine as long as I use the development server. Now I'm trying to configure it to run under apache, using fastcgi. The following message is being showed:

```
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/lib/fcgi.rb:54:in `for_fd': not a socket file descriptor (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/lib/fcgi.rb:54:in `default_connection'
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/lib/fcgi.rb:40:in `each'
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:27:in `run'
        from ./dispatch.fcgi:20:in `<main>'
```

Looks like the problem is something related to sockets in ruby, to make it easy, I've isolated the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
s=Socket.for_fd(STDIN.fileno)
```

When I try to run the code above, the same message is being showed:

```
/tmp/test.rb:5:in `for_fd': not a socket file descriptor (ArgumentError)
```

Since I'm not a ruby programmer, I would like to understand, what is happening?

Comment: Do you run it in docker?

Comment: @fl00r no. BTW, I'm running in a CentOS 6.2. Ruby was installed via yum.